# How to add type annotation to self parameter of the decorator of class method?

Tags: python, annotations, python-decorators

So, I have a decorator for a class like this

```py
def something_todo(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def decorator(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # do something
        return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return decorator
```

I want to have type annotation to `self` parameter in the decorator. But, writing like this is not working

```py
def something_todo(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def decorator(self: SomeClass, *args, **kwargs):
        # do something
        return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return decorator

class SomeClass:

    def __init__(self):
        # init here

    @something_todo
    def some_method(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # some process
```

And it even gets worse if I write the decorator and the class in different scripts. This will likely be happened

```py
ImportError: cannot import name 'SomeClass' from partially initialized module 'someclass' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

The reason why I did this is for clarity so people know that my decorator is only for that class method. Also, I would easily check all methods or properties of the class in the editor without the need to open the script that contains the class.

### EDIT

So this is the recap of the solution:

Let's say I have 2 scripts. One contains the `class`, and one contains the decorator function. For example,

```py
# inside decorators.py
def something_todo(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def decorator(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # do something
        return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return decorator
```

and

```py
# inside someclass.py

from decorators import something_todo

class SomeClass:

    def __init__(self):
        # init here

    @something_todo
    def some_method(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # some process
```

If I want to add a type annotation to `self` parameter in the decorator, I couldn't just do this

```py
# inside decorators.py

from someclass import SomeClass

def something_todo(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def decorator(self: SomeClass, *args, **kwargs):
        # do something
        return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return decorator
```

Because it will raise `ImportError` when I tried to import the class inside another script. So, to prevent the error, I could just do this

```py
# inside decorators.py

from someclass import *

def something_todo(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def decorator(self: "SomeClass", *args, **kwargs):
        # do something
        return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return decorator
```

And it works fine.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: Is your difficulty addressed by PEP 612, Parameter specification variables?

Comment: @Samwise not working as if it raise error like what I said at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two useful tricks:

1. Forward-declare types as string literals, e.g. `self: 'SomeClass'`
2. Use [callable protocols](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protocols.html#callback-protocols) for more flexibility in defining callable `TypeVar`s.

```
import functools
from typing import cast, Any, Callable, Protocol, TypeVar


class SomeMethod(Protocol):
    def __call__(
        _self,
        self: 'SomeClass',
        *args: Any,
        **kwargs: Any
    ) -> Any: ...


_SomeMethod = TypeVar("_SomeMethod", bound=SomeMethod)


def something_todo(f: _SomeMethod) -> _SomeMethod:
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapper(self: SomeClass, *args, **kwargs):
        # do something
        return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return cast(_SomeMethod, wrapper)


class SomeClass:

    def __init__(self):
        # init here
        pass

    @something_todo
    def some_method(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # some process
        pass


@something_todo
def foo():
    print('error: Value of type variable "_SomeMethod" of "something_todo" cannot be "Callable[[], None]"')
```

Comment: do both tricks solve circular import error? Because I have so many decorators that I have to write them in different script than the class script.

Comment: Should work fine, but I don't have your actual code to test with.  I'm a little curious why you have so many decorators that are only used within a single class -- sounds like the class itself might need to be broken up.

Comment: I'm using decorator because I realised that I need to change state (from database) everytime I run a method and change it back after it done to prevent calling other method while a method is still running. If I prepend and append my method manually, it will need so much work. That's why I'm using decorator.

Comment: Sounds like a good use for a context manager.

Comment: Also -- do you have a jillion different decorators to change different pieces of database state?  That would be a good thing to parameterize (you can have decorator functions that take parameters to the decorator, and this obviously works with context manager functions too) rather than copying+pasting a bunch of different versions of the same function.

Comment: Ah, why didn't I think of context manager? But, some decorator is not just for changing state. And nope, I don't have that. I only have 3 type of decorator, check connection to database decorator, change state decorator, and fill argument decorator.

Answer (score 0):

you did not return the decorator function. try adding the line `return decorator`. there is nothing wrong with the implementation if i understand your question correctly.

```
from functools import wraps
def something_todo(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorator(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # do something
        print("test decorator")
        return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return decorator

class SomeClass:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @something_todo
    def some_method(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("test some method")
    
SomeClass().some_method()
```

prints :

```
test decorator
test some method
```

Comment: That's not the problem. My problem is about type annotation. I already fix the missing pieces of return decorator.